# .htaccess - Removing a subdirectory from the URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bitnami

So I have a site currently located in a subdirectory, like so:

`http://example.com/wp`

We are moving this site to a new server, and it will no longer be in a subdirectory. However, we need all the old URLs to still work, so for example if someone tries to go to `http://example.com/wp/contact`, it will rewrite to `http://example.com/contact`.

This seems like it should be simple. I've tried this:

`<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</Directory>`

Which almost works, except it causes all the WordPress permalinks to 404 - so `http://example.com/contact` won't be found even though it should be the correct URL. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You may want to refer to [Methos I in this tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). One thing to note is it states to do this after installing in the root directory. Wordpress has a setting which dictates where links point. When you install, it sets that to whatever directory you install. If you installed on the subdirectory, it will be set to the subdirectory and therefore not work.

Comment: Have you done a search on your question in StackOverflow?

Comment: I have, none of the posted solutions work. The rewrite seems to work properly but it breaks WordPress' permalinks.

Comment: @D.R. There is no subdirectory, there just used to be. This is a totally new, upgraded copy of the old site

Comment: My guess is it's caused by the site url settings that I mentioned above. EDIT: I copied the wrong thing. One minute.

Comment: [Changing the Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). Have you verified this is set up appropriately?

Comment: If you had to estimate it, how many URLs do you think your site has?

Comment: Bitnami Developer here. I created a fresh Wordpress instance from Bitnami Launchpad. I added a contact page and copy-pasted the exact rules you added in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf`. These worked without issues. Did you add any plugins for rule rewriting? These may be conflicting in your installation.